# TeamCity Build Agent eligibility based on installed Powershell Module?

Tags: teamcity

Is there a way to restrict build agents to those which only have a particular Powershell module(s) installed?

Answer (score 1):

1. define which agent has this module
2. edit the buildagent.properties, add environment variables hasmodule=true

   `env.hasModuleEnvVar=true`
3. Open the configuration settings -> Agent Requirements

   1. Add new requirement
   2. Parameter Name = `env.hasModuleEnvVar`
   3. `Contains` true

Now you restricted your configuration, and it will be run only agent's which contains this module

Comment: You're talking about setting a manual process for setting environment variables for each agent that has to be maintained by hand?

Comment: yes, if you not able to maintain the `buildagent.properties` automatically